# Segfaulting before the faulty code is ran

Tags: c

I have a server/client set up using sockets. The server constantly listens for client messages. If it detects a specific message, it should add a node to a linked list. For debugging purposes, I wanted to print out the entire linked list.

However, whenever I include the following code to traverse through the list:

```
if( listHead )
            {
                Node * searcherNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
                searcherNode = listHead;
                while( searcherNode->next != NULL )
                {
                    printf( "Account name i: %s\n", searcherNode->accountData.name );
                    searcherNode = searcherNode->next;
                }
                free( searcherNode );
            }
```

it begins to segfault as soon as any message is sent, not just the one that would run this code. The debugging printf right before this loop doesn't show up or anything, so it happens very early in the code.

Running if( searcherNode->next != NULL ) did not cause any errors, and neither did running searcherNode = searcherNode->next; on their own. Also, changing the while statement to

```
while( searcherNode != NULL )
```

didn't help either.

Any ideas why this segfault is occurring? Thank you so much!

Edit: Same issue with this code:

```
Node * searcherNode = listHead;
                while( searcherNode != NULL )
                {
                    printf( "Account name i: %s\n", searcherNode->accountData.name );
                    searcherNode = searcherNode->next;
                }
```

Struct as defined in header file:

```
typedef struct bigNode
{
    struct bigNode *next;
    BankAccount accountData;  
} Node;
```

Relevant code in main file:

```
Node *listHead = NULL; //in global declarations
```

Node creation:

```
Node * nodeBuilder;
nodeBuilder->accountData = accountBuilder;
nodeBuilder->next = listHead;

listHead = nodeBuilder;
```

Comment: Just to point out something you might want to be aware of: C is a language in which you can have "time traveling bugs".  If you invoke [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), all bets are off...including that you might start getting crashes in perfectly valid code that appears to be chronologically prior to the place where you made the mistake.  And it wouldn't be considered a bug in the compiler--they aren't required to guarantee a program with any undefined behavior anywhere act valid anywhere else.

Comment: Could you please show how your struct is defined? In general is better to provide an [mcve], something we could test on our own.

Comment: Did that, and will do that in the future

Comment: The posted snipped for node "creation" doesn't allocate any memory for the node itself. Is that what you have in your actual code?

Comment: Don't use printf for debugging, use fprintf and print to stderr. fprintf(stderr, "my string");

Comment: `Node * nodeBuilder;` followed by `nodeBuilder->accountData` is invalid. The pointer `nodeBuilder` doesn't point anywhere, it's value is *indeterminate* (and seemingly random), and dereferencing the pointer will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I fixed that using `malloc` but I'm still getting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you [shouldn't really cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/). Secondly, that `malloc` creates a memory leak since you immediately make the pointer variable `searcherNode` point somewhere else.

And that reassignment is probably what makes your program crash: Since `searcherNode` will not point to the memory you allocated with `malloc`, then the call to `free` will attempt to free something which should not be free'd. In fact, this will attempt to free the last node in the list, without removing it from the list.

If the memory for that last node was not allocated with `malloc` then you can't pass the pointer to `free` as that will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). If the memory was allocated with `malloc`, then your next attempt to dereference the last (now free'd) node will also lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The simple solution: Don't call `malloc` and most importantly don't call `free`.

---

What you do with

```
Node * searcherNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
searcherNode = listHead;
```

is in a way similar to

```
int myValue = 10;
myValue = 5;
```

and then wondering why `myValue` is not equal to `10`.

Comment: Maybe it should also be pointed out that the allocation is useless in the first place. OP is traversing the list to print its content.

Comment: I appreciate that detailed description, as I'm sure you could tell I'm pretty new to C and malloc is going right over my head.

However I tested it without malloc as shown in the edit, but still get the same issue

Comment: @TimSPazda Then the problem is most likely how you create your list. Please try to show us an [mcve], including the creation of a list (and of course exhibits the problem you have).